# align a central button to bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

In my screen layout contain a central button, i want to align that button to bottom of the screen.  I tried with some code, but it became terrific...

my xml code as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button 1"/>

    <RelativeLayout 
       android:id="@+id/belowLayout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Left"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_width="75px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="..."/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Right"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

screen shot

[image]

thanks

Comment: check my answer!! it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_width="75px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnButton2"
        android:text="..."/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` like this:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_width="75px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="..."/>
```

Comment: @harekrishna what if you set android:layout_alignParentTop="false" AND android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop using px here. It might be the reason for your problem. Simply try it like this using dip,

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="..."/>
```

**EDIT 1**

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="..."/>
```

dip-density independent Pixels.

Here is the output,

[image]

Comment: i want central button is smaller than other

Comment: i can't like to change size of central button

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
    android:layout_width="75px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="..."/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
android:layout_width="75px"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the `"@+id/btnButton3"`